# How to detect slow internet speed in mobile apps?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I am developing a mobile app. And I want to treat very slow internet connections as if we were offline.

Getting this information from Network Signal Strength is not enough as we can have a strong Wifi and very slow Internet.

I am looking for a simple way to detect these slow connections. Any ideas ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49855013/2827025

Comment: You can't really detect "slow internet connections". Just like you can have strong WiFi, you could have a very fast connection to google.com, but at the same time a very slow connection to SomeOtherDomain.com. You'll need to set up your own timing for your specific data requests.